# Number value echoed from evaluation

Tags: help, characters

What does the (#o3, #x3, ?\C-c) output in the echo area (next to the 3) represent? Here I've simply evaluated

```
(+ 1 2)
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different views of 3 as octal, hex and a char.

Comment: Thank you. Where would I find this in the manuals?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea where I learned this.